# QlineEdit and signal & slot

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

I have created a widget with `QLineEdit` and `QLabel`, I want to get input from QlineEdit and display it with `QLabel`. I have used Signal and Slot connection, I do not know what I do wrong, but it is not working correctly. I would like to get both values from `QLineEdit` and later show it.

Current window

[image]

what I want?

[image]

Code:

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class WinDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    currenttextedited = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WinDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setGeometry(300,300,350,300)

        self.setWindowTitle("Signal & Slot")

        self.propertyWidget = PropertyWidget()

        section_lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        section_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Name: ")
        section_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('')

        length_lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        length_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Input a number:     L = ")
        self.length_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('1000')
        self.length_edit.setInputMask("999999")
        self.length_edit.setFocus(True)

        thick_lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        thick_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Input a text: T = ")
        thick_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('')

        section_lay.addWidget(section_label)
        section_lay.addWidget(section_edit)

        length_lay.addWidget(length_label)
        length_lay.addWidget(self.length_edit)
        length_lay.addStretch()

        thick_lay.addWidget(thick_label)
        thick_lay.addWidget(thick_edit)
        thick_lay.addStretch()

        VB_lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        VB_lay.addStretch()
        VB_lay.addLayout(length_lay)
        VB_lay.addLayout(thick_lay)
        VB_lay.addStretch()

        buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox()

        buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel
        |QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept) 
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addLayout(section_lay, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addLayout(VB_lay, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.propertyWidget, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(buttonBox, 3, 0, 1, 2)



        self.length_edit.textEdited.connect(self.textchanged)

    def textchanged(self, text):
        print(text)
        self.currenttextedited.emit(text)

class PropertyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(PropertyWidget, self).__init__(parent)        
       HB_lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
       self.Displaylabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('')
       HB_lay.addWidget(self.Displaylabel)
       HB_lay.addStretch()



@QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
def Display(self, text):
    try:
        L_Display = int(text)
        T_Display = int(text) 
        fmt = "L = {}mm\nT = {}mm"
        self.Displaylabel.setText(fmt.format(L_Display, T_Display))
    except ValueError:
        print("Error")        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = WinDialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to samples in the image you want to show different texts but you are converting the same number to whole: `L_Display = int(text)` and `T_Display = int(text)` so how do you expect to show 2 different texts?, obviously the function display needs 2 entries (2 different entries to `self` plus I have changed to lowercase since it is recommended that the functions have a lowercase name).

Now the logic is as follows: if any of the texts of length_edit or thick_edit changes then you must call `display()` passing the new texts. So the solution is to use a slot that connects to the `textEdited` signals of both `QLineEdit`s and in it obtain the text and pass the texts.

Finally I see that you want the `QLineEdit`s receive only numbers so one option is to use a `QIntValidator` so that only numbers are acceptable (another better option is to use `QSpinBox` instead of `QLineEdit`)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class WinDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WinDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setGeometry(300,300,350,300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Signal & Slot")

        self.propertyWidget = PropertyWidget()

        section_lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        section_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Name: ")
        section_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('')

        length_lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        length_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Input a number:     L = ")
        self.length_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.length_edit.setFocus(True)
        val_lenght = QtGui.QIntValidator(0, 100000, self.length_edit)
        self.length_edit.setValidator(val_lenght)

        thick_lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        thick_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Input a text: T = ")
        self.thick_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        val_thick = QtGui.QIntValidator(0, 100000, self.thick_edit)
        self.thick_edit.setValidator(val_thick)

        section_lay.addWidget(section_label)
        section_lay.addWidget(section_edit)

        length_lay.addWidget(length_label)
        length_lay.addWidget(self.length_edit)
        length_lay.addStretch()

        thick_lay.addWidget(thick_label)
        thick_lay.addWidget(self.thick_edit)
        thick_lay.addStretch()

        VB_lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        VB_lay.addStretch()
        VB_lay.addLayout(length_lay)
        VB_lay.addLayout(thick_lay)
        VB_lay.addStretch()

        buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox()

        buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel
            | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept) 
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addLayout(section_lay, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addLayout(VB_lay, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.propertyWidget, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(buttonBox, 3, 0, 1, 2)

        self.length_edit.textEdited.connect(self.onTextEdited)
        self.thick_edit.textEdited.connect(self.onTextEdited)

    def onTextEdited(self):        
        l = self.length_edit.text()
        t = self.thick_edit.text()
        self.propertyWidget.display(l, t)

class PropertyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(PropertyWidget, self).__init__(parent)        
       HB_lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
       self.Displaylabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('')
       HB_lay.addWidget(self.Displaylabel)
       HB_lay.addStretch()

    def display(self, l, t):
        try:
            L_Display = int(l)
            T_Display = int(t) 
            fmt = "L = {}mm\nT = {}mm"
            self.Displaylabel.setText(fmt.format(L_Display, T_Display))
        except ValueError:
            self.Displaylabel.clear()       


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = WinDialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @ZarKha If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank. On the other hand, do not edit my answer, if you have any problems related to my solution edit your question and add what is necessary to indicate with which part you have some inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. That works now. Regarding comments above, I am quite aware of it, I have different texts and should be having 2 different entries, the function would receive. idea behind getting length_edit and thick_edit text within construction of function is a brilliant solution. I have franckly created similar call function in some other scripts, but I face and challenge difficulty, made me to overlook it.